# Fluid simulation mesh baking issue

Tags: mesh, particles, fluid-simulation

I created a simple fluid simulation with cube as domain and sphere as flow object (geometry) in Blender 2.82. After baking the data I played the animation, the particles simulated as expected. Then under mesh section, I checked 'mesh' and click on bake mesh, and waited for it to be 100%. When it was finally done, I played the animation, it behaved in a weird way. The flow object takes shape of domain at the end. Seems like the mesh was not baked. Can someone please explain whats wrong with my simulation ?
[image: Fluid simulaiton]

Comment: Try setting the object visibility to textured.

Comment: It worked. Thank you